# How do I make printf() print output in the correct order?

Tags: c, output, printf

I have a simple working function that creates a table logging file information.

However, `printf` prints my output in the wrong order. I tried using `fflush(stdout)` to flush the buffer but it didn't change anything.

The function:

```
void printTable(char *libraryName)
{

   printf("%-40s%-30s%-25s%-20s\n", "[File Name]", "[Creation Time]", "[Version]", "[Size]");
   fflush(stdout);
   printf("%-40s%-30d%-25d%-20f\n", libraryName, getCreationTime(libraryName), getVersion(libraryName), getSize(libraryName));
   fflush(stdout);

}
```

The get functions are defined in a seperate file and give accurate output.

After compilation, the output looks like this:

```
[File Name]       [Creation Time]            [Version]       [Size]
125 kB
Version: 1.0.0.0 [6-02-2020 03:32:21 PM] Objects.dll
```

But it needs to look like this:

```
[File Name]       [Creation Time]            [Version]       [Size]
Objects.dll       [6-02-2020 03:32:21 PM]     1.0.0.0        125 kB
```

What do I need to do to my printf() function to get the correct order output? I've tried flushing the buffer and rearranging order of the functions. Is it possible to get the output in the correct order without writing a separate printf() statement for each function?

Comment: printf puts things in the order that you specify.  I think there is a problem with the values returned by your functions.  Do the strings contain any special characters, such as \r?

Comment: It is clear that your function do not return what you expect them to return. For example, `Version:` can only come from your getters. They are also most likely output other charcaters - carriage return is most likely. You do not need `fflush`, `printf` flushes after `\n`.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You have `%d` and `%f` in your printf statement, but according to your desired output those cannot be correct

Comment: `[6-02-2020 03:32:21 PM]` is not an integer - neither is `1.0.0.0`.  `125 kB` is not a floating-point value.  Are your functions *returning* a value or *printing* a value to standard output?

Answer (score 5):

The code you posted is fine and flushing isn't the answer. There's no way `%d` specifier could print strings like `[6-02-2020 03:32:21 PM]` and `Version: 1.0.0.0`, nor could `%f` result in `125 kB`.

I suspect your `get` functions are *printing* their results rather than *returning* them, something like:

```
int getCreationTime(char *libraryName)
{
    printf("[6-02-2020 03:32:21 PM] ");
}

int getVersion(char *libraryName)
{
    printf("Version: 1.0.0.0 ");
}

double getSize(char *libraryName)
{
    printf("125 kB\n");
}
```

I'm not sure what you *are* returning. Perhaps nothing? I have the feeling that you've got some compiler warnings you're ignoring. If so, read them, and address them!

If you're wondering why the results are mixed up it's because C doesn't proscribe that function arguments be evaluated in any particular order, such as left-to-right. It looks like `getSize` is being called first followed by `getVersion` and `getCreationTime`. Finally, the `printf` we see prints `libraryName`.